# Bash syntax error near unexpected token `else'

Tags: shell

I have written a simple script in bash. But when am running it, it is giving the error in title.

```
#!/bin/bash

unix_OS=`uname`

function_aix()
 {

   echo "This is AIX os"

  }


function_other()

 {

   echo " This could either be Linux/Solaris/Hp-UX"

  }

if [ $unix_OS == AIX ]
then

 echo "executing aix function"
  function_aix()

else

 echo "other function"
  function_other()


fi
```

Any Suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: when using functions, you don't/can't use `()`s. Just pass any args needed, i.e. `myFn arg1 "arg 2" arg3`. Good luck.

Comment: After removing Paranthesis, it worked fine. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call a function in bash, you shouldn't put the `()`
And if your function takes arguments, you can just put them next to the function call: `my_function "first" "second"`

```
#!/bin/bash

unix_OS=`uname`

function_aix()
{
   echo "This is AIX os"
}

function_other()
{
   echo " This could either be Linux/Solaris/Hp-UX"
}

if [ $unix_OS == "AIX" ]
then
  echo "executing aix function"
  function_aix
else
  echo "other function"
  function_other
fi
```

Comment: I have written a script with nawk which is working correctly. But, i got a suggestion that "nawk" is not installed in most servers. Please update it to use awk. When i use awk, in solaris, am geting the below error.                       awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Answer (score 0):

While calling the function, you don't need to call function name with paratheses ().
Replace the lines as follows :

```
.... 
if [ $unix_OS == "AIX" ]
 then
    echo "executing aix function"
    function_aix
else
    echo "other function"
    function_other
....
```

Comment: After removing Paranthesis, it worked fine. Thanks a lot :)